# How to get rid of MUI-Datatable "selected rows" panel on the top of a table

Tags: mui-datatable

Does anyone know how to get rid of 'selected rows' panel on the top of a table when some rows are checked or to place the panel to the bottom as in default material ui data grid component?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change selectToolbarPlacement in the MUIDatatable options: 'none', 'above', 'replace'. By default it is 'replace'.
As described [here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables):

> Controls the visibility of the Select Toolbar, options are 'replace' (select toolbar replaces default toolbar when a row is selected), 'above' (select toolbar will appear above default toolbar when a row is selected) and 'none' (select toolbar will never appear)

Comment: Thanks, I did the following to work:  `const options = {selectToolbarPlacement: 'none', ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS selector to hide the selected rows toolbar:

```
.MUIDataTableToolbarSelect-root-89 {
/* visibility: hidden !important; */
display:none !important;
}
```

If you want to hide the row entirely (which I assume you do), you can use the `display none !important` line. Otherwise, you can use the commented out line of `visibility: hidden`.